# Writing Python pandas dataframe row slices to a file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I've got a CSV file with 4 columns, first column being `case id` (which is repetitive).

```
========INPUT csv file=============
case_num, serial,binary,review
23,29983, 1, "lorem ipsum ,lorem ipsum"
23,298829, 1, "Hi there"
29, 20020, 0, "hickery dickery dock"
29,298829, 1, "Hello there"
29, 28220, 0, "dickery dock"
```

I'm trying to filter all rows based on unique number of case ids only.

```
input=pandas.read_csv("inp.csv")
case_id=fl["case_num"]
case_id.sort
with open("out.csv","w") as fl:    
    for i in case_id.unique():
        fl.write(([input['case_num']==i].iloc[0].values))
```

Output:

```
[23 '29983' 1
 'lorem ipsum ,lorem ipsum'] #<type 'numpy.ndarray'>

[29 '20220' 0
 'hickery dickery dock']     #<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

As you can see the output is being written out in different lines, but I want them properly as one row each line split by comma.

=====DESIRED OUTPUT=======

```
23, '29983', 1,  'lorem ipsum ,lorem ipsum'
29 ,'20220', 0,  'hickery dickery dock'
```

To put it simply, if I've read some rows from a dataframe (generated using a csv file), then how do I write the selected subset of rows exactly in the same format (as was the input csv file) to an output csv file.

Comment: Please show your desired output, it's unclear exactly what you're after

Comment: @EdChum please check, have added desired output. Basically how do you select a row from a dataframe (populated froma  csv file) and write the output exactly as it was in the input file

Comment: Can you add sample of your input file?

Comment: @jezrael added input sample file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print df
   case id case_num no                        text
0       23  '29983'  1  'lorem ipsum ,lorem ipsum'
1       23  '29983'  1  'lorem ipsum ,lorem ipsum'
2       23  '29983'  1  'lorem ipsum ,lorem ipsum'
3       23  '29983'  1  'lorem ipsum ,lorem ipsum'
4       29  '20220'  0      'hickery dickery dock'

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='case id')
print df
   case id case_num no                        text
0       23  '29983'  1  'lorem ipsum ,lorem ipsum'
4       29  '20220'  0      'hickery dickery dock'
```

Output to csv by [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df.to_csv(filename, sep=',', index=False)
case id,case_num,no,text
23,'29983',1,"'lorem ipsum ,lorem ipsum'"
29,'20220',0,'hickery dickery dock'
```

Comment: But I want to write the output of "print df " to a csv file. (each column seperated by a ","  and with column names if possible)